# Extract numerical data in Matlab or Python from a file with text in random order

Tags: python, matlab

I need to extract numerical data from the file below for plotting a line. More than one plot is exported and each plot is separated by row `ZONE J=1, T="export"`.  Also, they are small line plot sections that can combined to form a single long line. Each section here have different number of rows. Some has 2 rows and some has 3 rows(see the first and last section).

How can extract this data and make one single line plot?

Text File:

```
VARIABLES = "X", "Y", "Z", "Z"
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.113503    -9.99998e-05  0.261068      0.261068
-0.117146     -0.0001       0.25939       0.25939
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.122865     -9.99998e-05  0.258381      0.258381
-0.117146     -0.0001       0.25939       0.25939
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.122865     -9.99998e-05  0.258381      0.258381
-0.132332     -0.0001       0.259991      0.259991
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.162484     -9.99998e-05  0.270972      0.270972
-0.153354     -0.0001       0.267005      0.267005
-0.148184     -0.0001       0.264219      0.264219
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.  You need to show what you have tried and explain why it isn't working.

Comment: Can you please explain the coordinate format? Why are there two (identical?) `Z` components?

Comment: Does each subsection need to be a different line segment (e.g. non-continuous line where each segment should be separate) or you genuinely just need the numbers minus the "ZONE"parts?

Comment: @TheBlackCat : I have tried different things in Matlab such as hdrload. But the problem with them is that they take the first header and then stop reading more. Then there are other function files in Matlab where you can give the Format spec, but that does not work since the format changes.

Comment: @excaza : They are printed in this format from a software. But, that is not the big issue here. :)

Comment: You need to actually show what you have done.  Just describing it isn't enough.  You need to provide code, explain what you want, show what you get, and explain how what you get is different from what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from itertools import product
def getPoints(l,n):
    strPoints = [l[i:i+n-1] for i in range(0,len(l),n)]
    points = [list(map(float, row)) for row in strPoints]
    return points

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
f = open('data.txt','r')
d = ''.join(f.readlines())
data = re.findall("(?<=\"export\"\n)([-.\d\se]*)",d)
coords = []
for l in data:
    coords.append(getPoints(re.findall('([+-]?\d*\.\d+(?:e[+-]?\d+)?)',l),4))
print(coords)
for each in coords:
    linePoints = list(zip(each[0],each[1]))
    ax.plot(linePoints[0],linePoints[1],linePoints[2])
plt.show()
Axes3D.plot()
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: DEMO]

As your question was about extracting the numerical data, I stored it in `coords` as a list. with the `data.txt` as input, the `coords` contains following after executing the script:

```
[
   [
      [
         -0.113503,
         -9.99998e-05,
         0.261068
      ],
      [
         -0.117146,
         -0.0001,
         0.25939
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         -0.122865,
         -9.99998e-05,
         0.258381
      ],
      [
         -0.117146,
         -0.0001,
         0.25939
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         -0.122865,
         -9.99998e-05,
         0.258381
      ],
      [
         -0.132332,
         -0.0001,
         0.259991
      ]
   ],
   [
      [
         -0.162484,
         -9.99998e-05,
         0.270972
      ],
      [
         -0.153354,
         -0.0001,
         0.267005
      ],
      [
         -0.148184,
         -0.0001,
         0.264219
      ]
   ]
]
```

**CONTENTS OF DATA.TXT**

```
VARIABLES = "X", "Y", "Z", "Z"
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.113503    -9.99998e-05  0.261068      0.261068
-0.117146     -0.0001       0.25939       0.25939
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.122865     -9.99998e-05  0.258381      0.258381
-0.117146     -0.0001       0.25939       0.25939
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.122865     -9.99998e-05  0.258381      0.258381
-0.132332     -0.0001       0.259991      0.259991
ZONE J=1, T="export"
-0.162484     -9.99998e-05  0.270972      0.270972
-0.153354     -0.0001       0.267005      0.267005
-0.148184     -0.0001       0.264219      0.264219
```

Comment: @hillman, I took only 2 points to draw line even if there are more columns